# How do I specify a condition to copy values from one array to a sub array

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and learning c# and In array A I have peoples ages and I want to copy the values  < 18 and >65 to array B. How can I do this using else and if.

Comment: Try *Linq*: `var B = A.Where(item => item < 18 || item > 65).ToArray();`

Comment: The question you asked is very common on SO and have plenty of answers. Feel free to continue reading C# book you've started and you soon be able to use answers linked as duplicate. If that still not enough please [edit] question to clarify what you know and what you tried so people can offer concrete help (it's hard to know what explanation each person needs - also explaining how to access elements of an array or syntax of `if` is generally out of scope)